# Laravel Echo is not listening

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-7, laravel-websockets

I set up an event and new channel :

```
class TaskCreated implements shouldBroadcast
 {
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
public $task;

public function __construct(Task $task)
{
    $this->task = $task;
}

}
```

and installed Echo and set it up

```
 import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'pusher-key',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true
});
```

then I call the TaskCreated event when a task is posted

```
event(new TaskCreated($task));
```

However, the issue is Echo doesn't listen to pusher logs or ANYTHING. even though in laravel-websockets the event was created as an api-message.

here is vue js Echo implementation :

```
 mounted () {
        axios.get('/tasks').then(response => (this.tasks = response.data));

       Echo.channel('taskCreated').listen('TaskCreated', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
            this.tasks.push(task.body)
        });
```

in the dashboard :

`api-message        Channel: taskCreated, Event: App\Events\TaskCreated 19:01:55`

*UPDATE*

Now when I tried to connect with WS the connection status is pending for 10 seconds then finished with an error WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. AND Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

Request URL: wss://127.0.0.1/app/local?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.2&flash=false

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
 key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
 wsHost: window.location.hostname,
 wssPort: 6001,
 disableStats: true,
 enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
```

Comment: Could you check console? there might be some errors.

Comment: Remove the dot before `TaskCreated`. The dot implies that you have have a custom named event. You can add a custom name by adding a `broadcastAs()` function in the event class and returning a string with the custom event name.

Comment: @UzairRiaz no errors or logs in the console. Network - WS status is 101

Comment: `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/utf8.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ndjpnladcallmjemlbaebfadecfhkepb/editor/config.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ndjpnladcallmjemlbaebfadecfhkepb/editor/content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: can you confirm if the events are firing from the backend? check laravel-websockets dashboard at **{base_ur}/laravel-websockets**. Also, laravel echo constantly keeps sending requests to **wss:{url}** and **ws:{ur}**, and if you dont run `php artisan websockets:serve`, it will produce errors in console so check for those errors and post them here. You can also check network in browser dev tools by setting the filter to all requests to check those requests.

Comment: laravel-websockets dashboard is receiving messages and WebSocket server is running and displaying connection ID and sending message logs :( been two days I tried to create new projects but all act the same ....

Comment: could you contact me at https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/zt-eau36fgx-k1KWjR7fmNdqfvlJouderw. I can help you if I get to know the problem in detail. Can't keep asking you to try things here in comments.

Comment: just did plz check

Answer (score 5):

i dont see `broadcastOn` method in TaskCreated event if you have it in your code just use broadcastAs method too like this:

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'task.created';
}
```

and in vue component listen for event like this:

```
Echo.channel('taskCreated').listen('.task.created', (e) => {
            this.tasks.push(task.body)
        });
```

more info: https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting
but about laravel-websockets i use it recently and have similar problem and check their github repo turned out they have some open issues for this error that they didnt fix. i love spatie packages but for this one tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server is my first choise and easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

for anyone out there, after many attempts here is what I found ... you MUST have pusher credentials set in your env. and broadcast.js. I tried a lot with Laravel 7 to set it without the credentials ( no luck ) otherwise many issues from Google Chrome and network requests will blow up. this is for me and hopefully, this will work for you

Comment: It would be so nice if you could give us some clue about what you meant. I have been trying to run my Laravel 7 - Vue Application on a live server even if it works on localhost.

Comment: I haven't tested on a live server yet

Comment: Not the best formatted answer.. ..but certainly solved this exact issue for me. 
I removed the `process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY` and `process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER` constants from bootstrap.js, and replaced them with the actual values.  It now works.  Thanks AlmoDev.

Comment: To above commenter, that might be because you need to prefix with VUE_APP

So use VUE_APP_MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

In your `TaskCreated` event:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
   return new Channel('task.created');     
}
```

and in your Vue:

```
Echo.channel('task.created').listen('TaskCreated', (e) => {
            this.tasks.push(task.body)
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 6.2 use socket.io-client@2.4.0

Comment: BRO YOU SAVED MY 24 HOURS THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

As Kabelbaan said, remove the dot but go to the debug console and just refresh your app to start with. You should see connection and subscription for your tasks channel. If you don't, you can start debugging the connection rather than pushing dispatching the event. Also, I gather the copy & paste is just incomplete but your window.Echo statement is incomplete.

Comment: I removed the dot and still same thing. restarted all servers ( including Apache) and still same thing. window.Echo is complete! is there anything missing ?

Comment: @leo0019 Try using the `event(new TaskCreated($task))` function since that is how all events are fired in the official Laravel docs or by using `Event::fire(...)`. Could you also show us the channels.php?

Comment: `event` and `broadcast` didn't work for me. channel.php has only one route that's not related to tasks because its a public channel

Comment: laravel-websocket already getting `Channel: tasks, Event: App\Events\TaskCreated` but Echo isn't listening

Comment: @leo0019 I see that your channel name is `'tasks'` so make sure to change the channel correctly in the front end aswell. `Echo.channel('tasks').listen(...)`

Comment: that was a typo I changed it to tasks but still, the console has no errors, and dashboard is reviving events.

Answer (score 0):

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.
>
> Request URL:
>   wss://127.0.0.1/app/local?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.2&flash=false

You have possibly a problem with your **ssl certification**. You are using **wss** which connects on **https only**. You should check out your ssl cert or use **ws** instead.

Plus tip:

I would use socket.io + redis combo instead of pusher.

- Server side: https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server
- Client side: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting have socket.io
  section