# PrivateChannel 403 error Laravel Echo Pusher Laravel Websockets local setup

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I am getting a 403 on broadcasting/auth route.

I am using Laravel websockets package for web sockets and I have the below setup

```
- Backend Laravel server ( on port 8000 )
- Laravel Websockets Server ( laravel is running on 8001 and websocket server on 6001 )
- Standalone Ionic React app ( on port 8100)
```

Now everything works when I am trying Public Channel but when I try Private Channel it fails.

[image]

in the above screenshot of Laravel sockets dashboard I can see connection made as this is the same socketId which went with the request.

I am using Laravel Sanctum for Authentication.

PFB :- my client side code

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: window.localStorage.getItem('token')
      ? `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('token')}`
      : '',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
  };
  const options = {
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'abcsock',
    authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8001/api/broadcasting/auth',
    authorizer: (channel, options) => {
      return {
        authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
          axios
            .post(
              'http://localhost:8001/api/broadcasting/auth',
              {
                socket_id: socketId,
                channel_name: channel.name,
              },
              { headers, withCredentials: true }
            )
            .then((response) => {
              callback(false, response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              callback(true, error);
            });
        },
      };
    },
    wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
    wsPort: 6001,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    forceTLS: false,
  };
```

Code from Laravel Websockets Server

api.php file

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

NewNotification.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;

use App\AppNotification;
use App\User;

class NewNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $notification;
    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(AppNotification $notification, User $user)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        $notification = $this->notification;
        return [
            'id' => $notification->id,
            'title' => $notification->title,
            'description' => $notification->description,
            'button_text' => $notification->button_text,
            'is_read' => $notification->is_read,
            'created_at' => $notification->created_at,
            [
                'notification_for' => $notification->notifiable
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage($this->toArray($notifiable));
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('Notifications.' . $this->user->id);
    }
}
```

channels.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Broadcast::channel('Notifications.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
}, ['guards' => ['sanctum']]);
```

I have attached whatever I felt was sufficient to explain the issue and for you to troubleshoot but if you need anything more please ask.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hello @Dhaval,
please could you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856972/laravel-echo-sanctum-websockets-pusher-nuxtjs-spa
I really need your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i liked this package because its wrote in php but its sortof abandon and a lot of issues that not solved.

alternative of this server is laravel-echo-server(as laravel docs recommends) very easier to use.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61704796/7908390 more info if you can work with laravel-sockets im glad to see a new example

Comment: maybe as my last option I will try that but for now I want to wait to see if anyone has a fix for this situation

Answer (score 0):

Have you added authentication for your channels.php? Please refer here:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#defining-authorization-routes
What does it look like?

I think you are doing everything correctly but you have not authorized your routes.

Comment: Yes I have added those in api.php and BroadcastServiceProvider as in the code snippets pasted above

Comment: yes but i mean, what does your channels.php look like? 
I cannot see it.

Comment: I also do not know what events you are emitting and on what channel.

Comment: I have added code of channels.php and NewNotification ( the notification that I want to send ) .. Once again its issue with PrivateChannel and not normal Channel.

Comment: Try:
        Broadcast::routes(["prefix" => "api", "middleware" => ["auth:sanctum"]]);
I don't think you need the guard.
You also mentioned websocket server is running on 8001. Shouldn't you point it to your backend (8000) for /api/broadcasting/auth

Comment: Basically the flow is this:

You login with echo.js with your auth token, laravel-websocket-server receives your token, and does a request to api/broadcasting/auth which is on your backend using your token string, if this jwt is correct, you will login as a user and your channel access will be granted if and only if your channels.php rules match. You will get another token and you use this to get all proceeding events.

Comment: so I have 2 separate servers 1 for websockets and 1 for backend so I am authenticating against my backend server?

Comment: Correct. That's what determines authentication. 

So i'll explain again. 

1) laravel echo will take your token and use it to send a request to backend/api/broadcasting/auth
2) this will return a token back which will be a token you use for echo
Please check the in-depth explanation here: 
https://mattstauffer.com/blog/introducing-laravel-echo/

There is a part where he mentions the 403.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error with Laravel & pusher.
I have fixed using `decodeURIComponent` and moving `BroadCast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']])` to `routes/api.php` from `BroadcastServiceProvider.php`

Also, add `withCredentials = true`.

```
const value = `; ${document.cookie}`
const parts = value.split(`; XSRF-TOKEN=`)
const xsrfToken = parts.pop().split(';').shift()
Pusher.Runtime.createXHR = function () {
                    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
                    xhr.withCredentials = true
                    return xhr
                }
const pusher = new Pusher(`${process.env.REACT_APP_PUSHER_APP_KEY}`,
                    {
                        cluster: 'us3',
                        authEndpoint: `${process.env.REACT_APP_ORIG_URL}/grooming/broadcasting/auth`,
                        auth: {
                            headers: {
                                Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': decodeURIComponent(xsrfToken)
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

I hope this helps a bit.